# NvChad color issues from inside GNU Screen window

Tags: screen, neovim, iterm

In iTerm2 , when I am trying to open nvim(NvChad) inside a GNU screen window, the colors are weird and all text background changes to green. I verified that  the `echo $TERM` gives `xterm-256color` in a terminal and also in a Screen window.

This is how my terminal looks like
[image]

everything works fine outside the Screen. help me point out what is wrong here

I tried setting up a different value to `$TERM` in `.screenrc`   by adding this line.
`term screen-256color` but this did not help.